# Simple Script With Logging

Tags: list, logging, vbscript, copy

I am trying to write a script that will copy files from folder A to folder B, it will copy only files that come from a list file.

I then need it to log any files that failed to copy.  Here is what I have so far, I just cannot get logging to work.

```
    Option Explicit

Dim Sour, Dest
Dim oFSO, sFile, oFile, sText
Dim objFSO, objFileCopy
Dim strFilePath, strDestination, strSource
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

strLoggingFiles = "C:\failedtransfer.txt"

strSource = InputBox("Enter source path information") 'Enter your source path here
strDestination = InputBox("Enter destination path information") 'Enter your destination path here

'Set the read of the input file and prompt for location
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFile = InputBox("Enter path to text document with files to be copied:")

'Open the read, get the file name of the file to be copied, and copy it to new location
If oFSO.FileExists(sFile) Then
   Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile, ForReading)
   Do While Not oFile.AtEndOfStream
      sText = oFile.ReadLine
      If (Trim(sText) <> "") And _
         oFSO.FileExists(strSource & "\" & sText) Then

         oFSO.CopyFile strSource & "\" & sText, strDestination
      Else
         WScript.Echo "Couldn't find " & strSource & "\" & sText
      End If
   Loop
   oFile.Close
Else
   WScript.Echo "The file was not there."
End If
```

Comment: I don't see any code that does the logging. Did you forget to write it?

Comment: I tried to write some logging code but none of it was working so I posted the part that was working, At the top you can see the strLoggingFiles where I had it create the logfile name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code. It'll log the source file names (full path) if they are missing or failed when being copied. Please note that in Vista/Win7+, you'll need Administrator rights if you want to put a file in the root directory.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Sour, Dest
Dim oFSO, oLog, sFile, oFile, sText
Dim objFSO, objFileCopy
Dim strFilePath, strDestination, strSource
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

strLoggingFiles = "C:\failedtransfer.txt"

strSource = InputBox("Enter source path information") 'Enter your source path here
strDestination = InputBox("Enter destination path information") 'Enter your destination path here

'Set the read of the input file and prompt for location
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFile = InputBox("Enter path to text document with files to be copied:")

'Open the read, get the file name of the file to be copied, and copy it to new location
If oFSO.FileExists(sFile) Then
   'Open/create log file
   set oLog = oFSO.OpenTextFile(strLoggingFiles, ForAppending, True)

   Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sFile, ForReading)
   Do While Not oFile.AtEndOfStream
      sText = oFile.ReadLine
      If (Trim(sText) <> "") And _
         oFSO.FileExists(strSource & "\" & sText) Then

         On Error Resume Next 'disable quit on error
         oFSO.CopyFile strSource & "\" & sText, strDestination
         If Err.Number <> 0 Then
             oLog.WriteLine strSource & "\" & sText 'log failed copy
         End If
         On Error Goto 0 'enable quit on error
      Else
         WScript.Echo "Couldn't find " & strSource & "\" & sText
         oLog.WriteLine strSource & "\" & sText 'log failed copy 'log missing source
      End If
   Loop
   oFile.Close
   oLog.Close 'close log file
Else
   WScript.Echo "The file was not there."
End If
```

Comment: It is logging the entire transfer, I just want to log failures.

Comment: Typo error, sorry. The `Er.Number` should have been `Err.Number`. It's updated now.

Comment: That worked, now my next question.  I wanted to change up the input box to a browse box, instead of strSource= InputBox("") Can I put strSource=objshell.browseforfolder(o, "select source folder",0)

Comment: Yes, using the `Shell.Application` object.

Answer (score 0):

At some point I got tired of writing logging routines over and over again, so I wrote a class ([CLogger](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/index.shtml#clogger)) as an abstraction layer for logging to different facilities (console, eventlog, file):

```
Set clog = New CLogger
clog.LogFile = "C:\failedtransfer.txt"
clog.LogToConsole  = False
clog.LogToEventlog = False

'...

On Error Resume Next
oFSO.CopyFile strSource & "\" & sText, strDestination
If Err Then
  clog.LogError strSource & "\" & sText & ": " & FormatErrorMessage(Err)
End If
On Error Goto 0

'...
```